# How do I access a component's prop value from within an event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple component with an event handler function. How do I get access to the props value? This doesn't do what I was epecting.

```
class Example extends React.Component {

    handleClick( event, id ) {
        console.log( id );
        console.log( this.props );
    }
```

.....

```
return (
    <tr onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <th scope="row">
```

.....

Answer (score 0):

```
return (
    <tr onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
        <th scope="row">
```

Answer (score 0):

or ES6

`<tr onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}>`